# How to alter auto incremented id in JPA to start id after checking max id from sql table?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement where I have to start ID after checking max ID from the data which is already inserted in same table. Let's say existing database have id's till 6. From JPA I am adding data. I want it's ID to be 7 and then auto increment further. How can I do the same? Is there any way I can do something from codeline rather than writing sql scripts?

I have put 
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
in my Person entity class. After I run my application I see, hibernate creates sequence - create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1. 
I have tried altering the sequence to point start with max (id)+1 . But it is showing syntactical error in SQL.

I have also tried alter table person auto-increment=max(id)+1.

None of them working. Please help.

expected result is - next added id =6, but actually I am getting primary key exceptions.

Comment: Why not define the ID column in the database as auto-increment and let the SQL server worry about the increment?

Comment: Thanks Dave, but JPA is creating database table. I have only mentioned @entity class.